# SherlockFragment (ABS)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here is my problem. Im using ABS. SherlockFragmentActivity works on API 11+ but on API10. it does not work. It crashes.. Actually I have an intent button that will get you to the Sherlock Fragment Activity. In my tablet. 4.2.2. It works. But on the emulator after pressing the button. (API10) it crashes.

here is my code.

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MenuActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager2);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00a9ec")));
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Lessons"), FragmentMenu1.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Inside Android OS"), FragmentMenu2.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Quizzes"), FragmentMenu3.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("About"), FragmentMenu4.class, null);
}
}
```

MY LOGCAT..

```
01-22 00:09:33.051: D/dalvikvm(295): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 77K, 51% free 2654K/5379K,     external 716K/1038K, paused 80ms
01-22 00:09:40.232: D/dalvikvm(295): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 32K, 50% free 2699K/5379K, external 1264K/1737K, paused 69ms
01-22 00:09:43.461: D/AndroidRuntime(295): Shutting down VM
01-22 00:09:43.461: W/dalvikvm(295): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.ccstsu.androidostutorialforccsstudents/com.ccstsu.androidostutorialforccss tudents.MenuActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock,   Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:976)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:902)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:855)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.setContentView(ActionBarSherlock.java:672)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:271)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.ccstsu.androidostutorialforccsstudents.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:22)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at       android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-22 00:09:43.511: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  ... 11 more
```